# Changing color according to size in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Guys I have a multy store cloth designer website in magento. There I have some products which have different sizes and each have different color. So all I need to do is that, I had created configurable products and thus created the dropdown for selecting the size. When user select a value, the color has to change with appropriate value. How will I achieve this? Is there anyway in Magento? Please Help.

Comment: Actually I didn't do any coding. I have added a configurable product using magento back end. My preference is doing it with magento back end without any custom coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have numerous ways.Either you write the custom codes or you can use the magento extensions named "Colour Swatch". You can get variety of extensions.Choose among them.The extension may not fulfill all of your requirement.You may need to customize it.

These are some of the extensions:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatch-extension-with-zoom.html
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/product-color-swatches.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-color-swatch.html

Hope this will help you.